# Disable history syncing on Chrome for Android

Tags: chrome-for-android

How can I disable Chrome syncing its history on my Android phone? I looked in settings, but I cannot see an option there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the

Main Android settings > Accounts > Google (related account) > Browser Sync

remove the tick should work